# Using Tag Groups: Displaying groups and adjacent tags of current post

Tags: php, posts, functions, tags

I am trying to use tag groups (plugin) and tags as a way to display basic info on a portfolio/blog website's posts. I have organised them as *ex. Tag Group: Year / Tags: 2012, 2013, 2014... etc and tag each post with one tag from each group. What I want to display on a post/project page is Year: 2013, - display the name of the group and the adjacent tag for this post only.

So far, I have made a table and managed to display only adjacent tag groups, but I cannot filter the tag for the post. As an output I get "Group: All tags in it".

I am building the site myself and started with all web coding from zero a couple of months ago, so any help would be appreciated. I think that I miss a condition in the "foreach" function, but I am not sure at all.

This is the code:

$groups = tag_groups_cloud( array( 'groups_post_id' => '0', 'orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC' ) , true );

```
            <table>
            <tr>
                <?php if ( $groups ) foreach ( $groups as $group ): ?>
                    <th><?php echo $group['name'] ?></th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ( $groups as $group ): ?>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($group['tags'] as $tag ):
                        ?>
                            <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $tag['link'] ?>"><?php echo $tag['name'] ?></a></li>

                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your request correctly, then you probably need a different parameter: **tags_post_id**

```
$groups = tag_groups_cloud( array( 'tags_post_id' => '0', 'orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC' ) , true );
```

I tried it and the output is only the tags of that post, but arranged in a table.

The parameter **groups_post_id** is used for selecting **groups** that are connected to the post, while **tags_post_id** selects the **tags**.

See the complete [description of the parameters](https://chattymango.com/tag-groups/tag-groups-shortcodes/#Parameters).